# How to select checkboxes with opacity:0.5

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

How to select checkboxes with `opacity: 0.5`?

Selector `:checkbox[style~='opacity: 0.5']` doesn't select them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$('input').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('opacity') == '0.5';
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method lets you write a function that will run for all the elements and will only include them in the result set if the function returns true.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('opacity') == 0.5;
}).addClass('marked');​
```

<sup>This will add a "marked" class on every element with 0.5 opacity.</sup>

**Note**: You should [use classes](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) instead of manipulating and querying CSS directly from Javascript.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much, bažmegakapa